# CKEditor - get editor data and custom widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I have following custom ckeditor widget code:

```
(function()
{
    "use strict";

    var jQuery = require("jquery"),
        Underscore = require("underscore"),
        $template = jQuery('<div class="section-wrapper">' +
            '<div class="section-label"><span class="section-label-user"></span><span class="cricon cricon-lock"></span><span class="status-icon cricon"></span><span class="section-label-text"></span><span class="section-label-loader"></span></div>' +
            '<div class="clearfix"></div>' +
            '<div class="section-content">' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>'),
        bindEvents = function bindEvents(editor, section)
        {
            if(typeof editor.config.sectionPlugin.handlers !== "undefined")
            {
                Underscore.each(editor.config.sectionPlugin.handlers, function(callback, eventName)
                {
                    section.on(eventName, callback);
                });
            }
        };

    CKEDITOR.plugins.add('section', {

        requires: 'widget',

        init: function(editor)
        {
            var self = this;

            // Register the section widget.
            editor.widgets.add('section', {
                inline: false,
                allowedContent: 'section[!data-cid]',
                draggable: false,
                // button is required for UPCAST processing? stupid bug?
                button: 'sectionbtn',
                init: function()
                {
                    var sectionContent;

                    this.$element = jQuery(this.element.$);

                    sectionContent = this.$element.html();

                    // create html structure
                    this.$template = $template.clone();
                    this.$template.find(".section-content").html(sectionContent);
                    this.$element.html(this.$template);

                    // set editable content
                    this.initEditable("content", {
                        selector: ".section-content"
                    });

                    bindEvents(editor, this);
                },
                bindToContract: function(contract, options)
                {
                    this.section_class = contract.get("sections").get(this.$element.attr("data-cid"));
                    if(!this.section_class)
                    {
                        this.$element.addClass("is-corrupted");
                        return false;
                    }

                    this.section_class.on("change:name", this.update, this);

                    this.update();
                },
                update: function()
                {
                    this.$element.find(".section-label-text").text(this.section_class.get("name") + " header" + Math.random());
                },
                upcast: function(element)
                {
                    return element.name === 'section';
                },
                downcast: function(widgetElement)
                {
                    return widgetElement;
                },
                destroy: function(offline)
                {
                    CKEDITOR.plugins.widget.prototype.destroy.call(this, offline);
                }
            });
        }
    });
})();
```

When I am using `ckeInstance.getData()` method then whole code (widget template) is returned.

Is there any way to define what `widget/getData()` should return?

I don't want to parse code returned by `.getData()` method. I think it should be done with ckeditor.

Comment: may be you can use { var data = CKEDITOR.instances['section'].getData(); }

Answer (score 2):

You got to expand your [`downcast`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget.definition-property-downcast) function in the definition of the widget. It should return [`element`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.htmlParser.element) or [`text`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.htmlParser.text) and this is where you control the the widget's representation in data. Of course, once you define it, make sure the [`upcast`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget.definition-property-upcast) function is able to decode such an representation from data back into DOM (i.e. your template).

For instance, your downcast could be like

```
function( widgetElement ) {
    var el = new CKEDITOR.htmlParser.element( 'div', {
        'data-content': this.editables.content.getData()
    } );

    el.setHtml( 'foo' );

    return el;
}
```

if you were interested in nothing but the content of nested editable in a `data` attribute. It would convert your widget into

```
<div data-content="HTML of nested editable">foo</div>
```

once you call `editor.getData()`. If you write a corresponding `upcast` that extracts `data-content` and re–builds the DOM so it again looks like your widget template, then you have a full state machine that converts the widget between data and DOM.

In short `downcast` function is a kind of encoder (DOM->data) and `upcast` – a decoder (data->DOM).